# first time trying to run a project on RubyMine and getting an error about incompatible library version

Tags: ruby, rubymine

The error from the RubyMine terminal is:

```
/bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=2.7.5 /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv exec ruby -x /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/bundle exec ruby /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development'"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    27: from /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    26: from /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/rails:4:in `require'
    25: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
    23: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    22: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    21: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    20: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    19: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    18: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    17: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/railties-6.1.6.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    16: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    15: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    14: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    13: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    12: from /Users/user1/srccompanyl/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    10: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
     9: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
     8: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
     7: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
     6: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
     5: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
     4: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
     2: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
/Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/activesupport-6.1.6.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/user1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.5/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle (LoadError)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How do I debug and fix? I tried running `bundler install` but same `incompatible library version`. Do I need to make sure the rbenv version match? How do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean that it fails when you try to run Rails server via IDE? Does it run if you launch it manually from the Terminal?

Comment: runs from the terminal, but not from the IDE

Comment: Do you mean that the very same command `/bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=2.7.5 /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.2.0/libexec/rbenv exec ruby -x /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/bundle exec ruby /Users/user1/srccompanyl/bin/rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -e development'"` being run from the Terminal, works fine?